# Android project building fails after adding Flutter module

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, flutter-module

I'm trying to add a Flutter module to an existing Android app, I tried as Docs step by step https://docs.flutter.dev/.../add-to.../android/project-setup.

but it fails when running and throws this error:

> Execution failed for task ':app:mergeLibDexWidamDebug'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:wDebugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Failed to transform flutter-debug.jar (project :flutter) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=24, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Could not find flutter-debug.jar (project :flutter).

Can you help me, please?